# Do I need a special coding add-on or something to open recently edited Google Doc files via my synced Dropbox?

Tags: google-drive

I have trouble converting Google Doc files to Word files on my Dropbox via CloudHQ Sync. What I mean is that I have my Dropbox and Google Drive sychronised, thanks to CloudHQ, where I can edit the original Word file in my Dropbox folder and it updates the same file in the Google Drive folder online.

However when I or another person edit the file on Drive it will no longer open the original Word file. Basically saying something about different coding when I try to open the file.

Do I need some sort of extra coding add-on for Word to access recently edited Doc files via my Dropbox?

Comment: It's unclear what you're after here. Are you talking about `.gdoc` files? If so, those are just pointers to the Google Documents files and can only be edited using the Google Drive web interface. If you want to download them as Word documents from the GDrive web interface. If that's not what you're asking, please [edit] your question to clarify.